# Vertical alignment problem when organizing image with tabular

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I would like to display multiple images organized by `tabular`. Here's my code, which demonstrate what I want to do.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{app2.png}&\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{v2.png}\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{h2.png}&\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{d2.png}\\
\end{tabular}& \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{v.png}\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{h.png}&\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{d.png}\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{Result}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, in the display result there is some weird vertical space, which I cannot figure out why it is there and how to remove it.

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please, make your code snipped compilable! Add to it `\documentclass{...}`, used packages, `\begin{document}` and `end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabular` has a default anchor on its vertical center, while `\includegraphics` sets content with its anchor on the baseline. The following recreates the problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
  \begin{tabular}{ c c }
    \begin{tabular}{ c c }
      \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-1x1} & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-1x1} \\
      \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-1x1} & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-1x1} \\
    \end{tabular} & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-1x1}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Result}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

You'll either have to correct the anchor of the `tabular`, or the anchor of the image:

- For the former, you can force the anchor using the optional argument of `tabular`. That is use `\begin{tabular}[b]{..}` for the inner/nested `tabular`, which will provide an anchor point on the `b`aseline, just like `\includegraphics` does.
- Alternatively,[`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `valign=c` places an `\includegraphics` image with a centred vertical anchor:

  [image]

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
    \begin{tabular}{ c c }
      \begin{tabular}{ c c }
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-1x1} & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-1x1} \\
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-1x1} & \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-1x1} \\
      \end{tabular} & \includegraphics[scale=0.2,valign=c]{example-image-1x1}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Result}
  \end{figure}

  \end{document}
  ```

  You'll have to `export` the `adjustbox` key-value options in order to use them as-is inside `\includegraphics`.